# GNU Assembly documentation

Tags: documentation, gnu-assembler

There are many GNU tools like autotools and especially for autotools there's a really detailed [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.71/autoconf.html), as well as for [make build system](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), but I didn't find any docs related to GNU Assembly syntax.

For example NASM has a very good [documentation](https://www.nasm.us/doc/), but is there something like that for GNU Assembly?

Comment: gas is distributed as part of binutils, so its documentation is under there as well https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/